# Android 4.0 Socket problems

Tags: android

Well, Android 4.0 doesn't allow networking on UI thread.
So I made a new thread.

```
public class NetThread extends Thread {
    BukkitController bc;
    Socket sock;
    ObjectOutputStream outstream;
    ObjectInputStream instream;
    boolean loaded=false;
    String ServerIP="192.168.123.103";
    String id="ssw";
    String pw="ssw";
    ArrayList<String> plist=new ArrayList<String>();
public void run(){
    try {
        sock=new Socket(ServerIP,3560);
        outstream=new ObjectOutputStream(sock.getOutputStream());
        instream=new ObjectInputStream(sock.getInputStream());
        //LOGIN
        outstream.writeObject("SIGN "+id+" "+pw);
    } catch (Exception e){}
        Object tmp;
        try{
        outstream.writeObject("PLIST");
        plist=(ArrayList<String>) instream.readObject();
        } catch ( Exception e){
        }


    loaded=true;
    while(true){}
}
public void Write(String msg){
    try {
        outstream.writeObject(msg);
    } catch ( Exception e){
    }
}
```

}

And in the UI thread, I made the object :

```
m_nt=new NetThread();
m_nt.start();
```

After testing with LogCat, I found that the source stops at:

```
sock=new Socket(ServerIP,3560);
```

How can I solve this?
I had no error, just frozen there.

Comment: can post the log with exception

Answer (score 0):

You cannot perform network IO on the UI thread on Honeycombe. Technically it is possible on earlier versions of Android, but is a really bad idea as it will cause your app to stop responding, and can result in the OS killing your app for being badly behaved. You'll need to run a background process or use AsyncTask to perform your network transaction on a background thread.

There is an article about [a link](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html)Painless Threading on the Android developer site which is a good introduction to this, and will provide you with much better depth of answer than can be realistically provided here.

Comment: Well, it was a simple problem - free DNS service by 'DYNDNS' didn't work. Thanks for your responce.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
try{
sock=new Socket(InetAddress.getByName(ServerIP),3560);
//more here
}
catch {Exception e}
{
Log.e("MyThread", "Error " + e.getMessage());
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Maybe you don't have acces to that ip and port. At work I don't have access outside the network and I get timeout exception. This exception came after 2-3 minutes. Maybe this is your problem. Try from command line telnet <ip> <port> to see if you have acces to that address.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using an Asynctask for handling your network code. 
though I have to admit it is strange your code just stops. 
If the server is not available you should get an exception.

for some additional information on AsyncTasks check [Android developer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Comment: Well, it was a simple problem - free DNS service by 'DYNDNS' didn't work. Thanks for your responce.